# sql update not executing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Apologies if there is another feed with this same problem, I have tried different suggested solutions but I still get an error, and I cant see why!

I want to update a row in my table using a html form. I have populated the form with the existing values, and want to be able to edit those and update them when the form is submitted, but I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'
>   in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/love-deals/admin/update_offer.php:46
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/love-deals/admin/update_offer.php(46):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/love-deals/admin/update_offer.php
>   on line 46

Here is the php / sql code:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
$updateTitle = trim($_POST['title']);
$updateDesc = trim($_POST['desc']);
$updateRedeem = trim($_POST['redeem']);
$updateStart = trim($_POST['start']);
$updateExpiry = trim($_POST['expiry']);
$updateCode = trim($_POST['code']);
$updateTerms = trim($_POST['terms']);
$updateImage = trim($_POST['image']);
$updateUrl = trim($_POST['url']);

$updateSql = 'UPDATE codes SET (title,description,redemption,start,expiry,textcode,terms,image,url) = (:title,:description,:redeem,:start,:exp,:code,:terms,:image,:url) WHERE id=:offerid';
$update = $db->prepare($updateSql);
$update->execute(array(':title'=>$updateTitle,':description'=>$updateDesc,':redeem'=>$updateRedeem,':start'=>$updateStart,':exp'=>$updateExpiry,':code'=>$updateCode,':terms'=>$updateTerms,':image'=>$updateImage,':url'=>$updateUrl,':id'=>$offerID));
}
```

and the html form:

```
<form id="update_offer" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" method="post" action="update_offer.php?id=<?php echo $offerID; ?>">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label class="col-md-12" for="title">Title</label>
            <input id="title" class="form-control col-md-12" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Offer Title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label class="col-md-12" for="desc">Description</label>
            <textarea id="desc" class="form-control col-md-12" name="desc" placeholder="Description" value="<?php echo $desc; ?>"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label class="col-md-12" for="redeem">Redemption</label>
            <input id="redeem" class="form-control col-md-12" type="text" name="redeem" placeholder="Where to redeem" value="<?php echo $redeem; ?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label class="col-md-12" for="start">Start Date</label>
            <input id="start" class="form-control col-md-12" type="date" name="start" value="<?php echo $startDate->format('Y-m-d'); ?>" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>" max="2021-12-31" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label class="col-md-12" for="expiry">Expiry Date</label>
            <input id="expiry" class="form-control col-md-12" type="date" name="expiry" value="<?php echo $expDate->format('Y-m-d'); ?>" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>" max="2021-12-31" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label class="col-md-12" for="code">Code</label>
            <input id="code" class="form-control col-md-12" type="text" name="code" placeholder="Code (if applicable)" value="<?php echo $code; ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label class="col-md-12" for="terms">Terms</label>
            <textarea id="terms" class="form-control col-md-12" name="terms" placeholder="Terms & Conditions" value="<?php echo $terms; ?>" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label class="col-md-12" for="url">Offer URL</label>
            <input id="url" class="form-control col-md-12" type="text" name="url" placeholder="Offer URL (if applicable)" value="<?php echo $url; ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label class="col-md-8" for="image">Image <img src="../images/offers/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="" style="width: 200px;" /></label>
            <input id="image" class="form-control col-md-4" type="file" name="image">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 pull-right">
            <button id="update" type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

what am i doing wrong?! Im still learning php etc, so please be gentle, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do spend some time reading the manual on the UPDATE syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html - What you have now, is INSERT syntax (to a certain extent).

Comment: you're adding parameter "':id'=>$offerID" which is not in the query...

Comment: Also, `$offerID` is undefined, as per what is posted.

Comment: So use both http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php while developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have wrong syntax for update statement, as other guys mentioned already, change:

```
UPDATE codes SET (title,description,redemption,start,expiry,textcode,terms,image,url) = (:title,:description,:redeem,:start,:exp,:code,:terms,:image,:url) WHERE id=:offerid
```

**Into**

```
UPDATE `codes`   
   SET `title` = :title,
       `description` = :description,
       `redemption` = :redeem,
       `start` = :start 
       `expiry` = :expiry 
       `textcode` = :code 
       `terms` = :terms 
       `image` = :image 
       `url` = :url 
 WHERE `id` = :offerid
```

Learn more about the SQL Update syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html).

Then, one thing more you have a mistake in `execute()`. Change your `:id` into `:offerid` like below:

```
$update->execute(array(
    ':title' => $updateTitle,
    ':description' => $updateDesc,
    ':redeem' => $updateRedeem,
    ':start' => $updateStart,
    ':exp' => $updateExpiry,
    ':code' => $updateCode,
    ':terms' => $updateTerms,
    ':image' => $updateImage,
    ':url' => $updateUrl,
    ':offerid' => $offerID
));
```

Comment: Mistake yes, but this doesn't fix it. If what OP's using for UPDATE syntax, I for one would have learned some new PDO guru stuff today.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well, my answer is strictly to help him to solve error which is related to the missing parameter with binding data. What do you mean saying it does not fix it?

Comment: The OP isn't using proper syntax for UPDATE. My comment to the OP includes a link for it, as does Saty's answer including proper syntax.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You are right, I didn't realize that first, I updated my answer.

Comment: Mind you, it would be really nice if PDO worked that way, would be a timesaver ;-)

Comment: Yea, that would be quite nice actually :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong syntax of Update

It would be

```
$updateSql = "UPDATE codes SET title =:title,
description =:description,
redemption =:redeem,
start =:start,
expiry =:exp,
textcode =:code,
terms :=terms,image =:image,
url =:url
WHERE id=:id";// write id instead of offset because you are binding ':id'=>$offerID
```

Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your replies. My original update syntax was actually as you mentioned, I had changed it when looking through some other solutions, and not changed it back, but either way, even with correct syntax, I still got the same error.

Looking through your replies, I can see that I have ':id'=> $offerID but have used :offerid in the sql code, which obviously needs to be updated, so thanks for pointing that out! Hopefully that will fix the problem...